# GWT BarChart how to reduce space between bars and remove start line

Tags: java, gwt

In my project I use GWT charts -

```
   <inherits name="com.googlecode.gwt.charts.Charts"/>
```

I want to remove vertical line from where all bars starts and also to reduce the space between bars. Is it possible? I have tried several times but I haven't got a success.
Here is my java code:

```
  BarChart chart = new BarChart();

  BarChartOptions opt = BarChartOptions.create();
  opt.setEnableInteractivity(true);
  opt.setTitle("Statistic");


  DataTable dataTable = DataTable.create();
  dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Name");
  dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Stocks!");
  dataTable.addRows(3);

  dataTable.setValue(0, 0, "Units");
  dataTable.setValue(1, 0, "Stock");
  dataTable.setValue(2, 0, "Invoices");

  dataTable.setValue(0, 1, 743644);
  dataTable.setValue(1, 1, 22628);
  dataTable.setValue(2, 1, 10);

  // Draw the chart
  chart.draw(dataTable, opt);
```

[image: Barchart]

```
I found the way to reduce the size between bars with this:
  ChartArea chartArea = ChartArea.create();
  chartArea.setHeight(50);
  opt.setChartArea(chartArea);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Removing Vertical Axis Line

You can only remove the vertical axis bar by setting it to the same color as the background. In this case, white:

> ```
> AxisOptions hAxisOptions = AxisOptions.create();
> hAxisOptions.setBaselineColor("#FFF");
>
> opt.setHAxisOptions(hAxisOptions);
> ```

[image]

If you also want to remove the grid lines, set them to the background color as well since the minimum number grid lines you can specify is 2:

> ```
> opt.setGridlineColor("#FFF");
> ```

[image]

If you want the axis line to look the same as a grid line simple set them both to the same color:

> ```
> AxisOptions hAxisOptions = AxisOptions.create();
> hAxisOptions.setBaselineColor("#CCC");
> opt.setGridlineColor("#CCC");
>
> opt.setHAxisOptions(hAxisOptions);
> ```

[image]

You can check the Google Charts documentation [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options) specifying all the possible bar chart options to verify this is the only way to achieve the desired effect. It is not simply a limitation of the GWT Visualization API.

### Reducing Space Between Bars

This doesn't seem to be supported directly by the GWT Visualization API but it is supported by Google Charts. With the addition of a native JavaScript method you can get around this limitation.

First, extend the *com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options* class to include the native method:

```
public class BarChartOptions extends Options {
    protected BarChartOptions() {
    }

    public final native void setGroupWidth(String groupWidth) /*-{
        this.bar = { groupWidth: groupWidth }
    }-*/;

    public static BarChartOptions create() {
        return JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast();
    }
}
```

The new setGroupWidth method will now allow you to specify the bar width as a string percentage. E.g. "95%".

```
BarChartOptions opts = BarChartOptions.create();
opts.setGroupWidth("95%");
// Set other chart options here

// E.g. Removing the axis line
AxisOptions axisOptions = AxisOptions.create();
axisOptions.setBaselineColor("#FFF");
opts.setHAxisOptions(axisOptions);
```

[image]